# Why laravel components is not rendered inblade file?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, alpine.js

in my Laravel 8 /  tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app
I create laravel component with a command

```
php artisan make:component  Admin/ListingHeader
```

but calling this component in one of my blade files, like

```
<div class="editor_listing_wrapper" x-data="adminCategoryListingComponent()">
    111111<x-admin.listing-header
    :icon-hint="'Categories of the app'"
    :items-length= "{{ count($categories) }}"
    :items-total-count= "{{ $totalCategoriesCount }}"
    />99999999
```

This component is not rendered, as I see in the browser: https://prnt.sc/zulwm0

I suppose I set a valid path in

```
<x-admin.listing-header
```

as the generated template is located as resources/views/components/admin/listing-header.blade.php

I prefer to create laravel components, but why it is not rendered? How to fix it?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**

```
app/View/Components/Admin/ListingHeader.php:
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Admin;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class ListingHeader extends Component
{
    public $iconHint= '';
    public $itemsLength= 0;
    public $itemsTotalCount= 0;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $iconHint, int $itemsLength, int $itemsTotalCount)
    {
        $this->iconHint= $iconHint;
        $this->itemsLength= $itemsLength;
        $this->itemsTotalCount= $itemsTotalCount;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.admin.listing-header');
    }
}
```

and resources/views/components/admin/listing-header.blade.php :

```
<div class="p-2 pt-6 mb-4 flex">
    <div class="w-10/12 justify-start align-top">
        <h3 class="m-1 text-center flex items-center d1">
            <x-icon-svg :icon="'category'" :title="'{{ $iconHint }}'"></x-icon-svg>
            <span class="ml-2">
                        {{ $itemsLength }}&nbsp;@choice('category|categories', $itemsLength) from {{ $itemsTotalCount }}
                        </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="w-2/12 m-1 flex justify-end items-center align-top d2">
                    <span @click="refreshCategoriesListing()" class="mr-5">
                        <x-icon-svg :icon="'refresh'" :title="'Refresh categories listing'" ></x-icon-svg>
                    </span>
        <span onclick="document.location.href='{{ route('admin.categories.create') }}'">
                        <x-icon-svg :icon="'add'" title="Add new category" ></x-icon-svg>
                    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**

I made some tests simplified example and removing component I created  a
a new component, but not under admin directory with a command :

```
PHP artisan make: component  ListingHeader
```

and I filled in app/View/Components/ListingHeader.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class ListingHeader extends Component
{

    public $iconHint= '';
    public $itemsLength= 0;
    public $itemsTotalCount= 0;

    public function __construct(string $iconHint= '', int $itemsLength= 0, int $itemsTotalCount= 0)
    {
        $this->iconHint= $iconHint;
        $this->itemsLength= $itemsLength;
        $this->itemsTotalCount= $itemsTotalCount;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        \Log::info(  varDump(-1, ' -1 render ListingHeader::') );
        return view('components.listing-header');
    }
}
```

and in /resources/views/components/listing-header.blade.php :

```
<div>
    <h1>resources/views/components/listing-header.blade.php::{{ $iconHint  }}</h1>
    <!-- Very little is needed to make a happy life. - Marcus Antoninus -->
</div>
```

and writing in parent index.blade.php :

```
111111<x-listing-header
    :icon-hint="'Categories of the app'"
/>222222
```

I see rendered text ok with valid value of $iconHint var
But if in parent index.blade.php to pass laravel value :

```
111111<x-listing-header
    :icon-hint="'Categories of the app'"
    :items-length= "{{ count($categories) }}"
/>222222
```

The component is not rendered with double params inside of the component text:  https://prnt.sc/103oq9y

Can not catch why so? If which way to pass the parameter?
I suppose component rendered on server-side and no alpine confusion is possible...

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your `listing-header` blade as well.

Comment: look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: I created a new app and uploaded it on github: https://github.com/sergeynilov/ComponentTest

Just on resources/views/welcome.blade.php page I inserted my component and it is not rendered
and I see in the browser : https://prnt.sc/109g7dc

But if to remove 2 line :
                                :items-length= "'9'"
                                :items-total-count= "'99'"

component is rendered and I do not see why.

Please take a look.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like error was in space  in a pair:

```
  :key-name= "KeyValue"
```

Without spaces it works ok "

```
    <x-listing-header
        :icon-hint="'Categories of the app'"
        :items-length="count($categories)"
        :items-total-count="$totalCategoriesCount"
    />
```